# TestCafe reload page and re-execute fixture hook

Tags: testing, automation, e2e-testing, page-refresh, testcafe

The common wisdom for reloading is using `await t.eval(() => location.reload(true));`.

However, with this approach, once the page is reloaded if you have installed anything using the fixture hooks, such as `testcafe-testing-library`, it will no longer be available.

Is there any way to re-execute the fixture hook?

Relevant GitHub issue raised https://github.com/testing-library/testcafe-testing-library/issues/28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use [the new TestCafe feature](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/inject-scripts-into-tested-pages.html) to inject client scripts into testing pages and your scripts will be available even after reloading.